# How to toast when I've done 5 push ups in MLKit Pose Classification

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, google-mlkit

so my problem is I've been trying to make the app toast when I've done 5 push ups but I can't make it work. I've been trying to write the toast code using the repsAfter value in the PoseClassifierProcessor, there's error because the class doesnt extend AppCompactActivity. After that I write the the toast code in another activity and use the value repsAfter value from PoseClassifierProcessor and I still can't make it work.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed this. So I just learned that there's a thing called Thread in developing Android Mobile App. What I'm trying to do is making the app show toast from the thread. I've fixed this problem by following answer from this. [Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875184/cant-create-handler-inside-thread-that-has-not-called-looper-prepare)

Comment: Good to give detailed answers with reasons.